# makefile backtic in rule not setting a variable

Tags: makefile

I have a makefile with the following rule ,

all:

```
echo `${PWD_COMMAND}`; \
r=`${PWD_COMMAND}`; export r; \
sdir=`cd $(srcdir); ${PWD_COMMAND}`; export sdir; \
echo "r $(r)"; \
echo "sdir $(sdir)"; \
libsrcdir="$$sdir/mpfr"; \
echo $(libsrcdir)
```

The echo ${PWD_COMMAND} works ok, I get back the correct directory,
but the r variable and the sdir variable are not set.
I get as output

```
"r "
"sdir "
"/mpfr"
```

Can anyone explain why this is not working??

Thanks, Bill

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming `${PWD_COMMAND}` is a make variable? As is `$(srcdir)`?

But what about `$(r)` and `$(sdir)`? Are those make variables or shell variables?

What's expanding them in that line?

Put `set -x` at the start of that long line and see what you get at output.

Hint: You won't get what you are expecting to see.

Double Hint: Compare `$(sdir)` in `echo "sdir $(sdir)"` (which isn't working) and `$$sdir/mpfr` (which, while you can't see that at the moment, is working).